# iOS UITableView row height set in storyboard doubles when application runs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

This must be the stupidest question and I'm sure it was covered in some basic tutorial, but here it is:

I'm using Xcode 6, and creating a new UITableView in storyboard. I get the default Row Height as 44. Whenever I'm running the application using simulator, and any of the iPhone 4s, 5, 5s, and 6, my row height changes to 88! For iPhone 6 Plus it triples.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to create a full length and height background for each custom cell in the Table View, so I've created images with size 44x640 (image1.png), and 88x1280 (image1@2x.png). But when I run the application, I noticed that the image1@2x.png is displayed all the time, and instead of being displayed in full, it gets cut off.

So, is there a guideline on how to make these sort of images that would go into table view cells? Should I make images as 44x320, 88x640 and 132x960?. Is there a tutorial I forgot to watch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say your row height changes to 88, how are you measuring that? In pixels? Because if you run the simulator, it's going to translate each point (your row height is 44 points) into pixels at 2 pixels per 1 point for the devices you mentioned (and 3 pixels per 1 point for iphone 6+). This is because it is simulating the relative pixel densities of the various displays you've chosen.

And it seems that your background images are twice as wide as they need to be. So yes, your suggestions are spot on. They should be:

44x320, 88x640 and 132x960

Comment: Yes, I'm taking a screenshot, and measuring it in pixels - the unit I'm most familiar with from using Photoshop. Thank you for clarifying it!

Comment: Sure thing. If you want a good detailed explanation of how points and pixels work on iOS devices, here's a good link: https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/10/23/the-point-of-resolution-independence-ios-and-iphone-6-plus/